# Changing values in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, binary

I am currently working the genetic algorithm, specifically in the mutations part, that takes binary numbers and want to convert some of the values in a string into another value.
For example,
`y = {01011101, 01111001, 10011011};`
I have written the following:

```
mutRate = 0.025;
For[i = 1, i < 3, i++,
  If[Random[] < 0.025,
   y[[i]] = StringInsert[y[[i]],
     ToString[RandomInteger[]],
     RandomInteger[StringLength[y]]]]];
Print[y]
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach this is to turn the numbers in y into lists of digits and to then add 0 or 1 (Mod 2) to each digit, where the 0 and 1 are selected with probabilities {3/4,1/4}. Hence:

```
y = {01011101, 01111001, 10011011}; 
digits = Thread[NumberDigit[y, #] & /@ Range[6, 0, -1]]
Mod[digits + RandomChoice[{3/4, 1/4} -> {0, 1}, {Length[y], 7}], 2]
```

and you can see that the output has changed roughly 1/4 of the digits.